# How can I use Windows to create a High Sierra USB flash drive installer from the disk image (.dmg) file not downloaded from Apple?

Tags: macos, mac, applescript, windows, bootable-disk

I have tried methods from previous OSes. My Mac will recognize my USB stick, but I get the error message "The path /System/Installation/Packages/OSInstall.mpkg appears to be missing or damaged" and can never get the Mac to boot. Both of my MacBooks are dead. So, I am left with my PC to try and get High Sierra functioning on my 2017 again. I have tried updating to the newest OS to no avail.

Comment: How would I go about downloading this disk image (.dmg) file from Apple?

Comment: There is no easy way from PC, https://techrechard.com/download-macos-high-sierra-10-13-6-dmg-file/  was the simplest route I could find.

Comment: Where in your link does it state a download is from Apple? All I can find are links to downloads from third parties. I changed your title to reflect this. Can you more precisely define which 2017 Mac you have? There may be other ways to get High Sierra installed where the downloads are directly from Apple.